# How to compile ffmpeg using libx264 static library?

Tags: ffmpeg, static-libraries

I had installed x264 static and dynamic library on Linux.

And I compile ffmpeg by `./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 && make`.

The executable program link to the x264 dynamic library

I want to know how to config ffmpeg link to the static library

Comment: Remove the dynamic library and re make, the new ffmpeg will link to the static library.
But is the any better way?

Comment: In the configure options you can explicitly set compilation with static libraries, check it out.